# how to send full html images in java-mail? I am able to send the regular html text

Tags: javascript, html, jakarta-mail

```
/*
* To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
* To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/

package jmail;

import java.io.File; import java.io.FileInputStream; import
java.io.IOException; import java.io.StringWriter; import
java.util.Date; import java.util.Properties; import
javax.mail.Authenticator; import javax.mail.Message; import
javax.mail.MessagingException; import
javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication; import javax.mail.Session; import
javax.mail.Transport; import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress; import
javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage; import sun.misc.IOUtils;

/**
*
* @author Admin
*/ public class HtmlJavaSend {

    public void sendHtmlEmail(String host, String port,
            final String userName, final String password, String toAddress,
            String subject, String message) throws AddressException,
            MessagingException,
            IOException {

        // sets SMTP server properties
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust","mail.man.com");


        // creates a new session with an authenticator
        Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
            public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(userName, password);
            }
        };

        Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, auth);

        // creates a new e-mail message
       Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(userName));
        InternetAddress[] toAddresses = {new InternetAddress(toAddress)};
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddresses);
        msg.setSubject(subject);
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());

        // set plain text message
        //msg.setContent(message, "text/html");
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\netbeansproject\\En\\web\\EnGt.xhtml")),
writer);
        org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\netbeansproject\\En\\web\\resources\\images\\logo_1.png")),
writer);
        msg.setContent(writer.toString(), "text/html");



        // sends the e-mail
        Transport.send(msg);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // SMTP server information
        String host = "mail.man.com";
        String port = "25";
        String mailFrom = "admin@man.com";
        String password = "XXX";

        // outgoing message information
        String mailTo = "t.@man.com";
        String subject = "Hello En User";

        // message contains HTML markups
        String message = "<i>Greetings!</i><br>";
        message += "<b>Wish you a nice day!</b><br>";
        message += "<font color=red>Admin</font>";

        HtmlJavaSend mailer = new HtmlJavaSend();

        try {
            mailer.sendHtmlEmail(host, port, mailFrom, password, mailTo,
                    subject, message);
            System.out.println("Email sent.");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Failed to sent email.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    } }
```

Comment: Just to clarify i can send the html text but now want to send images and pictures so, what will be the next steps in code?

Comment: See the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#sendmpr) for an example.

Comment: Thanks, Bill. Can you give me more specific that what shall i add in my code? can you type Any syntax example?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not going to write your code for you.  If all you know is copy and paste, there are plenty of examples on the internet.  First, you need to understand the difference between a single part message, which you have created, and a multipart message, which you need.  The FAQ link above has an example of the latter.  Replace your setContent call with the code in the FAQ, modified appropriately.  There are also lots of complete example programs available on the [JavaMail web site](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Samples).